# How to dispose after each test in parallel testing xunit?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, xunit, xunit2

My tests in Selenium Xunit 2.0 from different collection class run parallel and dispose method call once only. I want to call to dispose the method after each test run even if they run in parallel.

```
[TestClass]
    public class Basic : IDisposable
    {
       
        protected void StopDriver()
        {
            #capture screenshot here
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            StopWebDriver();
            WebDriver.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just stop the web driver and dispose of it in the `StopDriver` function?

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand your point. I need to implement dispose method if I donot then will get this message "Basic class doesnt implement interface member 'IDisposable.Dispose()'"

Comment: I never said you couldn't implement IDisposable.  But if it doesn't do what you need it to do ...

Comment: Can you please give example how to do this without IDisposable?

Comment: Move your calls to `StopWebDriver()` and `WebDriver.Dispose()` into your `StopDriver` method (assuming that's what StopDriver actually does).  Don't change anything else.

Comment: StopDriver is not a method of any SDK, it will not do as you expecting it to do.